# If I'm freezing live clams, purge before or after freezing?

Tags: cleaning

I buy live mussels and clams from Diana's Seafood in Scarborough, Toronto. It's far from  home, so I  go just once every one or two weeks. I always ["Purge" Clams Before Cooking to Get All the Sand and Grit out of Them](https://lifehacker.com/purge-clams-before-cooking-to-get-all-the-sand-and-gr-1763358061).

1. Mussels ought not be frozen,  right?

Thus I freeze live clams and eat my live mussels first.

2. I'm guessing I ought purge them BEFORE freezing, when they are still alive and can  eject the grit. If I freeze then purge, they're dead and can't discharge grit.

Comment: I think you answered your own question.  Better yet, have you tried it?  Maybe report back in an answer.  It is perfectly fine to answer your own question below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here provides 2 methods to preserve clams:

1. If you will cook these clams within future 7 days, you could just **refrigerate** them, just put whole package in the refrigerator, **and do purging before cooking**. Put clams in 2~3% salty water about 2 hours for purging.
2. If you need longer preservation, you could **freeze** them, but remember to **do purging before putting them in freezer**. Clams will be no longer alive after freeze and unfreeze, and purging will become failed.

It's the experience from me and my friends who love culinary, hope it helps :P

Note:
If your clams are **vacuum-packaged**, both **refrigerating** and **freezing** should be OK (Prefer refrigerating, closer to clams living temperature).
No matter what method preservation, cook and eat these fresh ingredients ASAP always better.